# Controller issue: How do I see "More Info" in Xcom Enemy Unkown

Tags: pc, controllers, xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm playing XCom Enemy Unknown on a PC using an XBox 360 controller. For some reason, I'm unable to see the "More Info" dialog. The keybinding shows up as `LS`, which I assume is the Left Stick. See screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of game]

The LS is used for navigating the soldier to a location, so I can't use it. When I switch to keyboard/mouse, I can see a nice button for More Info.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both of the thumb sticks on the XBOX 360 controller can be pressed down as buttons - they will noticeably click under your thumb when this is done correctly.

So, I think the game wants you to click the left thumb stick.

I've not played XCOM with a controller to know for sure, but since the icon tip is the term LS ("Left Stick", as you guess, sounds right) in a circle with a down arrow inside the circle, I think this is the most likely answer.

Comment: What the...wow! It worked! That never occurred to me, I always treated the analog sticks as delicate little things.